# grand total sum in php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sum

this may sound lame but i am stuck up with summing up the values retrieved from mysql.
i want to sum up the grand total of the sales invoice items that is retrieved from mysql database.
following is the code for sub total for each line which is fine.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($qry)){  
echo $row['b'] * $row['c'];
}
```

'b' is the quantity and 'c' is the price.all these values are retrieved from mysql and the no of rows is variable and all this is inside the while loop.
Now outside of the while loop, the last row, i want the grand total. can somebody point me in the right direction. i tried

```
echo SUM($row['b'] * $row['c']);
```

but this doesn't work and gives an error. i am sure i am doing it wrongly.

Comment: Are you sure your MySQL database is using Integer values for rows 'b' and 'c'? If they're using string values they'll be returned as strings. That's why it may not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$total = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($qry))
{  
  echo $row['b'] * $row['c'];
  $total += ($row['b'] * $row['c']);
}

// at the end, $total = grand total
```

Comment: thanks. it is not giving an error but the result is 0. can you advise me. may be scjosh is right it is picking up values as strings. what should i do to correct that please. thanks :-)

Comment: That answers the question, but don't you think it'd be much faster to make DB do that sum? IMO having PHP to dig through large result set isn't a good idea. +1 for working code though.

Comment: @slave you already have all the results, why wasting another query to get grand total?

Comment: @mmdel - I have no idea, you should include some records example , and table schema from your existing database.

Comment: @Slava - I originally thought the same thing, but the answer is really maybe. Notice that the sum is occurring on the values resulting from the multiplication of number and cost. At the least, it's another query, and that query will need to sum all rows of the results of the two multiplied values.

Comment: It works: http://codepad.org/HjJVRg1z Something I would suggest is to use another variable to store one calculation: http://codepad.org/Tqm8RinV

Comment: thanks guys. just ran another query and got the sum from mysql and got this done.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use SQL for things SQL does best?

```
SELECT SUM(b*c)
FROM table
```

Simple as that.